# How to register an app to respond to a custom URL scheme opening request?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

Like this:

```
NSString *stringURL = @"appname://";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

I slightly remember it was necessary to write a value-key to Info.plist. How?

Comment: You could see a detailed illustration with the updated 2015 version for Xcode 6 here http://stackoverflow.com/a/18480723/1780492

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add this to plist [image: screenshot].

The app will by called by @"readtext://" url

Comment: Xcode 4 looks completely different! Must I really repeat the bundle identifier for the URL type? It also asks for an Icon and Role.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be the question that I answered (with screenshots & source code) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8201724/how-to-register-a-custom-app-opening-url-scheme-with-xcode-4/22372904#22372904).

[image]

And I've posted a full walkthrough of how to do this on [my blog](http://mikesknowledgebase.com/pages/XCode/CustomURLs.htm).

Comment: You're welcome.  It's simple, isn't it, once you can see an example ?  It turns a two-hour headache into a 5-minute job !!