# How to open an iOS application from another iOS application

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6

Lets consider I have two application App A and App B. What I want to do is

1) I like to open an App B when I tap on a button in App A.

2) When the App B is open from that button tap from App A, I like to go back to App A from App B.

Is it possible in iOS ?

Thank you, -- Amit

Comment: (1) is possible if App B has a URL scheme; (2) is possible if App B is set up to do that kind of thing. Google "iOS URL scheme" for more information.

Comment: Don't forget to implement [x-callback-url](http://x-callback-url.com/)!

Answer (score 3):

Very Possible. It is solved with custom url schemes that you're app states:

[How to register a custom app opening URL scheme with Xcode 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8201724/how-to-register-a-custom-app-opening-url-scheme-with-xcode-4)'

[Launch an app from within another (iPhone)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419119/launch-an-app-from-within-another-iphone)

Then from App A tell UIApplication to launch App B's url and vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible if both application support it.

Both application can declare an URL scheme they handle, e.g. `applicationA://`. Opening the application can then be performed by

```
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"applicationA://launch"];
BOOL success = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

See [Implementing Custom URL Schemes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW50)