# Launch ipad application from attachment in email

Tags: ios, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, zip, file-manager, custom-url

I am sending a zip file containing images and text file as an email attachment in ipad. Now my required functionality is that I want to launch my app when user taps on attachment for downloading and save the zip file in documents folder of app. How can I accomplish this task?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot launch your iPhone/iPad Application by clicking on the attachment link in email. However, you can open your app by setting custom URL for your app.

For more information on setting custom URL for your app, you can check the question below, May be this way you can achieve your target :

[How to register a custom app opening URL scheme with Xcode 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8201724/how-to-register-a-custom-app-opening-url-scheme-with-xcode-4)