# Todays Extension container app action

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, today-extension

I know how to open hostApp from the todays extension. But i have no idea how to perform an action in hostApp, when it opens it only from the todays extension. Any suggestions.? thanks in advance.

Comment: I saw several apps, which do the same thing

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24019820/today-app-extension-widget-tap-to-open-containing-app   i think this link will help you.

Comment: URL Schemes can help on you.