# Launching Containing App from UIWebView in Custom Keyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, xcode6, custom-keyboard

Since you can only go the normal route for launching a containing app from a Today extension, and not a Custom Keyboard, I've been trying to do the hacky version of launching a UIWebView and launching the containing app through its URL scheme. Mostly been getting help from this post: [launch containing app from iOS8 Custom Keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24495362/launch-containing-app-from-ios8-custom-keyboard), but I'm not allowed to comment on answers since I'm new to stack overflow.

Anyways, doing it now, the UIWebView is popping up but is just showing a blank white square and not launching the URL scheme. Already tried accessing the URL scheme from Safari, and I know that launches the app, so not sure why its not doing anything. Code I have now in the method following when the right key is pushed is:

```
let urlkey = NSURL(string: "MYAPP://")
let webAppView = UIWebView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100))
let request = NSURLRequest(URL: urlkey!)
webAppView.loadRequest(request)
self.view.addSubview(webAppView)
```

Any ideas for why nothing in the view is loading, or other ways to go about launching a containing app from a custom keyboard appreciated. Using XCode 6.3 and Swift.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to launch another app through keyboard-extension.

Other extensions like today-widget-extension can use like below.

```
NSURL *pjURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"hostingapp://home"];
[self.extensionContext openURL:pjURL completionHandler:nil];
//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24019820/today-app-extension-widget-tap-to-open-containing-app
```

but, nothing happens in the keyboard-extension.

//I guess...

If you get success to implement launching app in the keyboard, the keyboard will not be accepted by Apple.

#### updated 15/09/14 :

[openURL not work in Action Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24297273/openurl-not-work-in-action-extension/28037297#28037297)

I found some people are trying that, so check this.

Some said their app accepted by apple.(I don't know it's true)