# iOS Containing app is not launched

Tags: ios, today-extension

I have a today extension for my app and I would like to be able to open the containing app from it. I have put what is necessary in my app's info.plist

```
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>iOSmyApp</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>com.company.myApp</string>
    </dict>
</array>
</plist>
```

And then I call the method `openURL: completionHandler:` from the extension:

```
NSURL * hostURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"iOSmyApp//:"];
[self.extensionContext openURL:hostURL completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
    NSLog(@"success opening - %d", success);
}];
```

I get 1 as value for success but the app is not launched. Also, it doesn't change whether I use `iOSmyApp` or `iOSmyApp//:`, however if I put something different I get a message about unknown URL. So obviously I am missing something but I can't find what it is.

**EDIT**

> RCNTodayExtension[1294:835478] Failed to inherit CoreMedia permissions
>   from 1282: (null)

This is the only error I get, I don't see how it could be related but I don't know what causes it either.

Thank for your help.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24019820/today-app-extension-widget-tap-to-open-containing-app

Comment: @Hugues can you put error code in comment,so we can get the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the thing is I had already seen this question and it seems to me that I have filled all the necessary steps. My method `openURL:` is called but the application in not launched.

Comment: I don't have any error, except something about CoreData but it doesn't seem related (I will still add it)

Comment: the URL scheme has this form anyway << urlscheme:// >>

Comment: @elio.d Indeed, it was really a stupid mistake, I changed iOSmyApp//: by iOSmyApp:// and it works. If you turn this into an answer I will accept it.

Comment: @HuguesDuvillier is not stupid it's just a typo :)