# Is it possible to start application from other application

Tags: ios, lifecycle

There are many ways to start application from another application in Android.

Is it possible to start application from another application in iOS? If possible, how do I do it?

Comment: Check this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8201724/how-to-register-a-custom-app-opening-url-scheme-with-xcode-4

Answer (score 2):

[image: Set Custom URL Schemes]
Yes, it is possible in iOS if provided the app has its URL Scheme set. If you want to open your app from any other your app you can set the custom URL Scheme in info tab of project settings.

To test, run your app, minimize and then open safari and type the URL you just set, hit GO and your app will open.