# Launch Podcast App With URL scheme

Tags: ios, objective-c, podcast

I'm trying to open the podcast app with a url like this

```
- (void)setupPodcast
{
    NSLog(@"setup podcast");
    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"pcast://podcasts.sdxme.org/RSS/default.aspx?ID=%ld", (long)[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"CustomerID"]];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:str]];
}
```

`2015-10-18 23:45:11.367 [29302:1691034] LaunchServices: ERROR: There is no registered handler for URL scheme pcast`

However it looks like the pcast scheme is no longer supported?  How can I open my own XML feed in the podcast app?

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8201724/how-to-register-a-custom-app-opening-url-scheme-with-xcode-4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe Apple changed their recognized podcast scheme and you should now use 'feed://...'.

Comment: Its looks like feed opens up the news app, and pcast opens up the podcast app, but only on the device with the podcast app installed.  not on the simulator.

Answer (score 3):

As per Swift 4,

We should use the below `url schemes` to open podcasts app from our app.

1. `Podcasts (Add Feed By URL)` —  `podcast://` (you can also add a feed URL after to auto-populate it)
2. `Podcasts (Browse)` — `pcast://` or `itms-pcast://` or `itms-pcasts://` or `podcasts://` or `itms-podcast://` or `itms-podcasts://` (displays a "can't connect" error)

Comment: I am able to get it to open macOS podcasts only with `pcast` or `podcasts`, but do you know how to have it prompt the user to subscribe to a feed?

Comment: Thanks, this works great for opening and prepolutating the feed url on both MacOS 12 and iOS 16: `podcast://example.com/feed.xml`

Answer (score 3):

MacOS Majave needs  pcast://
IOS  podcast://