# iOS 9 canOpenURL error for ADAL login

Tags: ios, swift, adal

This just stopped working in XCode 7.2.1 building against 9.2.1.

I'm using Microsoft ADAL from cocoapods.

This is the error:

```
canOpenURL: failed for URL: "msauth://broker" - error: "(null)"
```

I've already added msauth to my Info.plist file under LSApplicationQueriesSchemes.

I think I am going to downgrade to XCode 7 to see if that works.

Edit: I added the LSApplicationQueriesSchemes item to the MS ADAL cocoapod and now it's returning data but still giving the same error.

Comment: Are you sure that there is an app that is registered to handle that scheme?  Is this a simulator or real device?

Comment: Both simulator and real device. Ostensibly my own app would accept this URL to validate a security feature.

Comment: But if you haven't built an app that handles it, you will get that error.

Comment: I don't get what you're saying. That I shouldn't respond to it? Should I take out teh LSApplicationQueriesSchemes? Have you had this problem?

Comment: No, but if you call `canOpenURL:` for a scheme like `msauth://broker`, you have to also have an app installed on the device / simulator that is built to handle that scheme like here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12784399/3708242 You will need to build the other app that does something with the url "msauth://broker".  In other words, if you call canOpenURL with something like "twitter://blah" but don't have twitter installed, you will see that error.

Comment: Thanks. It is for Microsoft ADAL so I suspect they just need to rewrite their library to make it compatible with 9.2.1

Comment: Can you show the full log for the error?  I wonder if the call is coming from the ADAL cocoapod library.  Maybe you need to add it to the ADALiOSFramework Info.plist?

Comment: Wottle yes! I needed to do that for it to work. It works in OSes earlier than 9.2.1 just fine if I add the msauth to the plist of the ADAL cocoapod. I believe MS ADAL iOS library will need an update sooner than later.

Comment: So it's working now?  If so, I'll post an answer so others that are having this problem will know the correct solution.  I agree that the ADAL iOS CocoaPod will likely be updated soon to include this, if it still being maintained.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that for libraries within your iOS projects, the library's Info.plist needs to be updated to handle any custom URL schemes that the library may call `canOpenUrl` for. So if you have this issue, add the custom scheme to `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` in the library's Info.plist, **not** the application's Info.plist.

Answer (score 0):

On a real device it works, it's just weird output of the simulator.

Because it not able get some property settings on simulator.Please check on real device.