# safari link is not open in If www is missing iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, url, mobile-safari

I Referred a many links related to this issue,But I cannot able to find the answer.I am getting a dynamic url in my app...If the `url` contains http://www then it opens the link,If `www` is not present then this error occurs.Any Help on this.

I am using this code,

```
NSString *selectedurl=[self.SelectedItem objectForKey:@"url"];
selectedurl=[selectedurl stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];

NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:selectedurl];

   if (url.scheme.length == 0)
   {
    selectedurl = [@"http://" stringByAppendingString:selectedurl];
    url  = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:selectedurl];
   }

  if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:selectedurl]])
   {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:selectedurl]];
   }
```

[image]

Comment: are you added the application query schema in your plist

Comment: No,I will check for that.I refered this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8201724/how-to-register-a-custom-app-opening-url-scheme-with-xcode-4..What should I need to add my plist,because I am getting url for webservice It can be anything

Answer (score 0):

only the URL will start in `www` your page does not open`, you need to append the`http:` in front of the string, so try this

```
NSString *sentence = @"www.google.com";
NSString *searchWord = @"http";
if ([sentence rangeOfString: searchWord].location != NSNotFound) {
    NSLog(@"Yes , the search word is available");
}else
{
  // add the http in front of www using stringWithFormat
 }
```

or the alternate way

```
 NSString *string = @"www.google.com";
if ([string containsString:@"http"]) {
  NSLog(@"string contains http..!");
} else {
  NSLog(@"string does not contain http...!");
}
```

**choice-2**

I think what you are searching for is Universal Links. Check this documentation for it [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html). It's pretty simple and straight forward. And [here](https://blog.branch.io/how-to-setup-universal-links-to-deep-link-on-apple-ios-9) is a step by step explanation of how to support them. And afterwards, you can validate your own custom universal links [here](https://branch.io/resources/universal-links/) or here[enter link description here](https://limitless-sierra-4673.herokuapp.com)

Comment: are you try the deep linking, if yes check once in your plist contains valid url schema or not else try universal links

Comment: If the url http://www.hokeypokey.in/ It opens in safari..If it is like this http://zaica.dinein.in/veg/ it does not opens it shows me an error `the address is invalid`..No I didnt try with deep linking.Let me check

Comment: Thanks bro,will check