# Issues with custom Url Schemes

Tags: ios

I have an app lets say 2 apps - app1,app2
Lets say I open from app1 app2.
How can I send data back from app2 with custom url schemes,like in facebook app?
If I reopen app1 with url,I will see go back to app2,and its not good idea for my case.
I want to open app2 like presented modally,and dismiss it with returned data.Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can define custom URL Schema for your app from info.plist file. you can check existing Thread on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8201724/how-to-register-a-custom-app-opening-url-scheme-with-xcode-4) for this.

In your case,for example In app1- define custom url `myAppOneScheme` and in your app2, Define custom url `myAppTwoScheme`.

When you open app2 from app 1, Pass app1's url like this:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"myAppOneScheme://test?callerURL= myAppOneScheme"]];
```

from app2, handle openURL method:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {
    NSLog(@"url recieved: %@", url);
    NSLog(@"query string: %@", [url query]);
    NSLog(@"host: %@", [url host]);
    NSLog(@"url path: %@", [url path]);
    NSDictionary *dict = [self parseQueryString:[url query]];
    NSLog(@"query dict: %@", dict);
//   NSString callerurl = parse callerURL from query

//  store callerurl in user default or global variable. 
    return YES;
}
```

when you are done with operations in app2 and want to go back to app1, open caller url

```
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:"%@//testback?response=%@", caller url , datayouwanttoSendback]]];
```

---

Now, in your app1, again handle open url method and  parse response

Comment: Ok,in this case I will see go back to app1,after 

  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:"%@//testback?response=%@", caller url , datayouwanttoSendback]

from ios system api,like back to safari.am I right?

Comment: I want it to be like facebook
open modally from bottom to top and close it like dismiss controller