# What is customURLScheme in Firebase Dynamic Links?

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

In the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/ios/receive) it says to add the following lines to my `AppDelegate.swift`:

```
  // Set deepLinkURLScheme to the custom URL scheme you defined in your
  // Xcode project.
  FIROptions.default().deepLinkURLScheme = self.customURLScheme
```

From what I understand this should be the same link you put in your `info.plist`. However, I'm confused why in the [quickstart-ios repo](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/tree/master/dynamiclinks) they decided to make this equal to "dlscheme".

Can anybody help me understand what exactly this scheme is?

Answer (score 20):

*This is not clear in the Dynamic Links integration instructions — I ran into the same issue even though I work with these things all day at [Branch.io](https://branch.io) (full disclosure: we're an alternative/improvement to Dynamic Links).*

When configuring a custom URI scheme, you need to supply both an **Identifier** and a **URL Scheme**. Apple recommends using a reverse domain value for the **Identifier**, but since your bundle ID is also typically reverse domain format, these two often end up being identical.

By default, Firebase expects you to use your bundle identifier as your custom URI scheme. When you do this, their default configuration takes over and you don't need to specify the `FIROptions.default().deepLinkURLScheme = self.customURLScheme` line at all. The URI scheme config ends up looking like this, which is a bit counter-intuitive:

[image]

However, if you decide to use a value that is *not* your bundle ID for the URL Scheme (very common), then you DO need the `FIROptions.default().deepLinkURLScheme = self.customURLScheme` line. But you **also** need this one before it: `let customURLScheme = "somethingelse"`. You can see this [here](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/blob/master/dynamiclinks/DynamicLinksExampleSwift/AppDelegate.swift#L26) in the quickstart, and also where the URI scheme is defined in the `info.plist` file [here](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/blob/master/dynamiclinks/DynamicLinksExample/Info.plist#L32-L35).

Basically, the Firebase team tried to simplify things by assuming the bundle ID as the custom URI scheme value. This is not a *bad* option, but it can be confusing and as you can see, even their own quickstart project uses a more advanced config.

Comment: This is the second Firebase question I've seen you answer, which I find to be both amusing and admirable.  Can you shed any light on the `Icon` setting in your screenshot, and where that ends up appearing in dynamic link flow(s)?

Comment: @MattMc knowledge knows no bounds! Thanks for the kind words. I actually have no idea what the icon is for — I'd never really thought about it. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8201925/5394680) seems to suggest it's something to do with macOS

Comment: @AlexBauer can we test in build installed from Xcode? or  i need to upload to TestFlight to test this?

Comment: @sulabh you should be able to test Deferred link behavior via Xcode just fine — install the build, generate a link, delete the app, click the link and then follow it through to the App Site but DON'T install, and then install the build from Xcode again and open it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @AlexBauer ! Helped me after i found this root cause from their self diagnostic tool (https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/debug#ios_self-diagnostic_tool).