# How to configure iPhone/iPad file associations with Xcode 4.3?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, xcode4

Can anyone provide a pointer to an updated tutorial/example of setting up custom file associations on iOS using Xcode 4.3?

I've seen the following (*including Brad Larson's excellent answer*), but the handling of Info.plist in Xcode 4.3 is significantly different than any description I've seen:

- [How do I associate file types with an iPhone application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774343)
- [Importing/Exporting Documents on iOS](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/importing-exporting-documents-ios?dm_switcher=true)
- [How to register an app to respond to a custom URL scheme opening request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8201463)

I tried reviewing Apple's documentation, but "[Document Interaction Programming Topics for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010409-SW1)" was updated in Nov-2010.

None of the examples I can find discuss configuring it in the way Xcode 4.3 handles them - which includes separate "Document Type", "Exported UTIs", "Imported UTIs", and "URL Types" sections under the target/Build Info and includes different key names (e.g. "Description" vs. "UTTypeDescription")

Any pointers are helpful, a working Xcode 4.3 example would be fantastic.

Comment: You can still edit the info.plist file directly. Just follow the same procedure you would have used in older versions of Xcode, I think. The only thing that's different in the new Xcode is that there's a new summary section, which may be confusing you. Ignore it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on suggestions by @samson but I wanted to capture this answer for future searchers.

Find the `info.plist` in the Project Navigator.  Mine was under a "Supporting Files" group prepended by the application name (e.g. `MyApp-Info.plist`).  Right-click and "Open As > Property List".

Then by entering the described sections as follows I was able to be passed a fileURL from Mail:
[image: Document Types][image: Exported Type UTIs]

I should note a couple things for the record:

- I did NOT put document icons for my file type, but it would be **strongly** encouraged to do so.
- The property editor will try to auto-complete the names of properties, so it really gives you quite a bit more guidance than is apparent.