# Where do I find the iOS appname?

Tags: javascript, ios

How do I find out the name of an iOS app?

I'm trying to trigger an app to open on an iPhone from javascript with:

```
window.location = "appname://";
```

However, I didn't make the app and I don't know what to do replace `appname` with. So where on the itunes page or on the phone can I find out this information?

Comment: That's a custom URL scheme. You have to ask the developer of the app, or see if they have it published somewhere. The custom URL scheme of an app (if it has one) is entirely up to the developer, and can be completely unrelated to the name or any other piece of information about the app.

Comment: That's not the app name. What you need is the app's custom URL scheme. Keep in mind that not all apps have one. You need to ask the developer.

Comment: I was afraid people would say that. Thanks.

Comment: Hey, it is what it is, and that's it.

Comment: find an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8201463/how-to-register-an-app-to-respond-to-a-custom-url-scheme-opening-request

Comment: @GrzegorzKrukowski That's not a relevant link. The OP is creating their own custom scheme. They need to find the scheme of an existing app.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the application you want to find the URL for.
2. Download [iExplorer](http://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/).
3. Navigate to the application.
4. Open the `Info.plist` file.
5. If they have custom URL types it will be under `URL Types -> Item # -> URL Schemes -> Item #`

Should look like this. `myappurl` will be the url like `myappurl://`

[image]